# Python smtplib slower than PHP mail()

Tags: php, python, smtp, smtplib

I ported some PHP applications to Python.

To my surprise, performance dropped by ten times in the newsletter module (100k+ subscribers). I was expecting some overhead for using SMTP (I think PHP calls sendmail directly), but not that much.

How can I speedup Pythons mail delivery?

EDITED: For anyone digging this question, I solved this using [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) with 8 workers to delivery e-mail in background, with this setup I can deliver about 200K messages per hour. Celery integrates very well wit django, and AMQP rocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `mail()` does indeed use `sendmail`. You can do the same thing in Python by invoking it via [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: What then? Just pipe in msg.as_string()?

Comment: After invoking it with the appropriate options, sure.

Comment: By the way, I just decided to use AMQP, but thanks, I will accept your answer.